# CVE-2018-2783 - Can it be clarified on what the CVE here means?

Tags: java, security

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-2783 says that "Applies to client and server deployment of Java. This vulnerability can be exploited through sandboxed Java Web Start applications and sandboxed Java applets. It can also be exploited by supplying data to APIs in the specified Component without using sandboxed Java Web Start applications or sandboxed Java applets, such as through a web service." Does this mean that this will not apply for java applications like Hadoop or server side, but only for the ones running on the browser (like applets or java web start?)

Answer (score 1):

Since the CVE report says "Note: Applies to client and server deployment of Java.", this would indicate that it would affect Java applications running on a server side application, as well as a client side application.

Comment: Thanks. In "It can also be exploited by supplying data to APIs in the specified Component", by "Component", does it mean here that its referring to "Java Web Start Applications/Applets" or does it apply to "Component" column at https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/cpuapr2018.html?